# Crack the code: JavaRelated

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

I got a card with a text from a software company, and it tells me to decode it.
The only thing written on the card is the following code:

```
  bWpvey9vam9rYjMxMjZBZXpvYnVzYmRmL2Rwbg==
```

Might be Java related

Comment: Is there any story or background information available for this riddle? Might be needed to solve it. In what way exactly might it be related to Java?

Comment: Sorry, no more information is known

Comment: This probably came from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33392346/4475014)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string is base 64 encoded, decoding gives:

```
  mjo{/ojokb3126Aezobusbdf/dpn
```

The string `/dpn` gives a further clue how it needs to be deciphered; if you take the previous character in the ASCII table you get `.com`. Substituting each letter with the previous letter in the ASCII table gives the following email address. I have replaced @ with (at) to avoid email scrapers abusing this address.

```
  linz.ninja2015(at)dynatrace.com
```

Comment: @Gamow, how did you get the correct decoding? I also got the wrong decoding that first was given

Comment: @Ivo: I used the tool at https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: ...so... I know that it's just answering the question, but maybe the email address should be obscured in some way so crawlers don't eat it?

Comment: I have replace (at) with @ to stop email scrapers

Comment: So does that mean the question is basically an ad for Dynatrace?

Comment: This question was original posted on StackOverlow (since then it has been deleted). In that post @IvoBeckers commented that a recruiter had handed him a card with that `secret` code. I helped him decipher it not realising it was an email address. I suspect Dynatrace may actually not be too happy the solution has been posted here as it makes it easy to Google for it. I suspect they may soon create a new secret code containing a new email address.

Comment: @Jaco I didn't comment there. it probably was Mathias