# Crack the code (Java related)

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

I found a card of a company which must be several years old when cleaning my house. On this card, there is a riddle and I just can't figure it out. The code is the following:

```
k5aRhdGZ15HNz87JkZaR1Z6/m4aRnouNnpya0ZyQkg==
```

I am pretty sure it's something base64 encoded, however I can't decode it correctly. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crack the code: JavaRelated](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/crack-the-code-javarelated)

Answer (score 5):

If you decode then

> xor each byte with 255

you get an email

> linz.f(n2016nin*a@dynatrace.com

Comment: When I do that exact same thing, I get: 쩮ꮦ郞ﲰﱶ瑱ह⡣宣ﭿ, not no email.

Comment: i get what Bob said.  base64 decode, then...er... "apply logic" :)